# Find missing first and last digit of an integer divisible by $8$ and $9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Among grandfather's papers a bill was found:
>
> $$72 \text{ turkeys \$}-67.9- $$
>
> The first and last digit of the number that obviously represented the total price of those fowls are replaced here by blanks, for they have faded and are now illegible.
>
> What are the two faded digits and what was the price of one turkey?

Now this is how far I got, I realized that if convert the $ to cent I get the a integer. Now if this integer is divisible by 72 then it is divisible by 9 and 8. Now this is where I get stuck, they take 79- and state that this has to be divisible by 8 since 1000 is divisible by 8. But I know several digits that are less then 1000 that is divisible by 9 so why would it have to be 8 ? I'll post the full answer later.

Comment: Because for 9 you would need to get the sum of the digits but you have 2 unknowns so there is no possible way. With 8 you just need the the last 3 digits to be divisible by 8 so you can solve for one unknown digit.

Comment: Not following your objection.  $x6000$ is divisible by $8$ because $1000$ is.  Thus $x679y$ is divisible by $8$ if and only if $79y$ is.

Comment: Assuming spherical turkeys of identical mass...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the missing digits be $a$ and $b$ in that order; we know that $a679b$ is divisble by $8$. Since $a6000=a6\cdot1000$ is divisible by $8$, this means that $79b$ is divisible by $8$. $720$ is a multiple of $8$, so $79b-720=7b$ is a multiple of $8$, and the only possible choice for $b$ is clearly $2$.

Now we know that $a6792$ is divisible by $9$. This means that the sum of its digits is a multiple of $9$; that sum is $a+6+2\cdot9$, so $a$ must be $3$. The original amount must therefore be $\$367.92$.

Answer (score 3):

Using your realisation we get a679b (where a,b are digits between 0 and 9) is divisible by 72 and hence by 8 and by 9. 
Working modulo 8: 
$790 + b \equiv 0$ mod 8 
$-2 + b \equiv 0$ mod 8 and thus $b=2$.
Now the division rue for 9 gives $a+b+22$ is divisible by 9 $\implies$ a+6 is divisible by 9, so $a=3$. 
Collecting this information, the total bill was \$367.92 and each turkey cost \$5.11.